# WQL Query and displaying custom fields

Tags: sql, wql, sccm

I'm running a WQL Query from SCCM to grab a list of computers with one of two applications installed.  I'd like to display the name of the offending application in a column alongside the computer name.  Do you know of an easy way to do this?

Another way to accomplish this would be multiple Select Statements, of course.

My query code:

```
    select SMS_G_System_SYSTEM.ResourcelD From SMS_R_System inner
    join SMS_G_System_SYSTEM on SMS_G_System_5VSTEM.ResourcelD =
    SMS_R_System.ResourcelD inner join
    SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS on
    SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAM5. ResourcelD =
    SMS_R_System. Resourceld where
    (SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS. DisplayName like "%Chrome%") or

    (SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS,DisplayName like "%Firefox%”)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a column you add it to your select.

```
SELECT 
SMS_R_System.Netbios_Name0 as 'Name',
SMS_G_System_ADD_REMOVE_PROGRAMS.DisplayName as 'Software'
FROM
....
```

etc

Let me know if this helps...

Comment: Is this even doable in WQL, I'm pretty sure it isn't possible so why did the OP mark this as if it solved their problem? This is at best misleading as the syntax will work in SQL, not WQL.